Convergence of bootstrap variance estimator
Let $X = X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a random sample and let $X^* = X_1^*, \dots, X_n^*$ be a bootstrap sample drawn from $X$ with replacement.
Say $\hat \sigma_n^2$ is a consistent variance estimator, i.e., $\hat \sigma_n^2 \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} \sigma^2$ (unconditionally).
We want to show:
Conditionally on $X$, it holds that $\hat \sigma_n^{2*} \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} \sigma^2$.
In other words
$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P( | \, \hat \sigma_n^{2*} - \sigma^2 \, | > \epsilon \, | \, X ) = 0
$$

Assume we have been able to show the following:
Conditionally on $X$, it holds that $\hat \sigma_n^{2*} - \hat \sigma_n^2 \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} 0$.
In other words
$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P( | \, \hat \sigma_n^{2*} - \hat \sigma_n^2 \, | > \epsilon \, | \, X ) = 0$$

Does this already suffice? If yes, how can we formalize this?

The statement is incomplete: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P(\vert \hat\sigma_n^{2*} - \sigma_{}^2\vert >\epsilon \mid X) = 0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[\mathsf 1(\vert \hat\sigma_n^{2*} - \sigma_{}^2\vert>\epsilon) \mid X] = 0$. Note that there exists a measurable function $f$ such that $f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[\mathsf 1(\vert \hat\sigma_n^{2*} - \sigma_{}^2\vert>\epsilon) \mid X = x]$. So your statement lacks a condition on the $x$. I suppose you mean almost all $x$?

Hey @SydAmerikaner. I'm still trying to get my head around the question "what precisely do I need to show?". It's super hard since your solution is so tightly linked to almost sure convergence, whereas I only have stochastic convergence to work with. I will get back to this thread once I talked to other people about it. Thanks for your input meanwhile!

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, P)$ be the underlying probability space, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ iid copies of an real-valued random variable $X$ with non-negative finite second moment $\sigma^2$. I denote the distribution of $X$ by $P_X$.
I suppose that you want to show $$P_X\left((x_1, x_2, ...) : \text{$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\left[\mathsf 1\left\{\vert\hat\sigma_n^2{}^* - \sigma_{}^2\vert\leq\epsilon\right\}\mid X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ...\right] = 1$ for all $\epsilon>0$}\right) = 1,$$ i.e., the consistency holds for almost all real sequences $(x_1, x_2, ...)$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ and $(x_1, x_2, ...)$ be an arbitrary real sequence. Suppose that i) $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\left[\mathsf 1\left\{\vert\hat\sigma_n^2{}^* - \hat\sigma_n^2\vert\leq\epsilon\right\} \mid X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ...\right] = 1$$ for all $\epsilon>0$, and ii) $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\vert\hat\sigma_n^2 - \sigma_{}^2\vert = 0$ conditional on $(X_1, X_2, ...) = (x_1, x_2, ...)$.
Note that ii) is given if $E[X^4] < \infty$, and you mention that i) can be assumed.
Conditional on $(X_1, X_2, ...) = (x_1, x_2, ...)$, we have that $$\vert\hat\sigma_n^2{}^* - \sigma_{}^2\vert = \vert \hat\sigma_n^2{}^* - \hat\sigma_n^2 + \hat\sigma_n^2 - \sigma_{}^2\vert \leq \vert \hat\sigma_n^2{}^* - \hat\sigma_n^2\vert + \vert \hat\sigma_n^2 - \sigma_{}^2\vert$$ by the triangle inequalty. By i), there is an $N_1$ such that the first term is less than $\frac\epsilon2$ in probability for all $n\geq N_1$ in the sense of i), and by ii) there is an $N_2$ such that the second term is less than $\frac\epsilon2$ for all $n\geq N_2$. Therefore, $\vert\hat\sigma_n^2{}^* - \hat\sigma_n^2\vert \leq \epsilon$ for all $n\geq \max(N_1,N_2)$ in probability (by the Continuous Mapping Theorem: $Y_n + C_n \rightarrow Y + C$ in probability if $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of random variables converging in probability to $Y$ and $(C_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a real, deterministic sequence converging to $C$). That is,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\left[\mathsf 1\left\{\vert\hat\sigma_n^2{}^* - \sigma_{}^2\vert\leq\epsilon\right\}\mid X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ...\right] = 1.$$
Finally, since $(x_1, x_2, ...)$ and $\epsilon>0$ were arbitrary, we have that $$P_X\left((x_1, x_2, ...) : \text{$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E\left[\mathsf 1\left\{\vert\hat\sigma_n^2{}^* - \sigma_{}^2\vert\leq\epsilon\right\}\mid X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ...\right] = 1$ for all $\epsilon>0$}\right) = 1.$$

Thanks for your answer. Do I understand you correctly that in (ii) you assume convergence $|\hat \sigma_n^2 - \sigma^2| \rightarrow 0$ almost surely? Would the proof still work if we only have $|\hat \sigma_n^2 - \sigma^2| \rightarrow 0$ in probability?

I just can't imagine what happens to convergence in probability if we condition on $X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, \dots$. Would that also yield deterministic convergence?

With regard to your first comment, I don't think so. However, I don't have a definite answer (I have been looking for a counter example for quite some time; I discussed this issue with regard to conditional convergence in distribution in a question on MathOverflow).

If you have iid data and finite variance, the Kolmogorov condition $\sigma^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2} < \infty$ is satisfied. If you don't have iid data, the proof will become a lot more difficult

If you condition on $X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ...$, $(\hat\sigma_n^2){n\in\mathbb N}$ becomes a deterministic sequence. But $(\hat\sigma_n^2{}^*){n\in\mathbb N}$ is still a random sequence (the randomness comes from whether a particular $X_i$ is resampled or not. You could think of $\hat\sigma_n^2{}^*$ as being given by $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (W_iX_i - \overline{W_iX_i})^2$, where $W_i=1$ if $X_i$ is resampled and $W_i=0$ otherwise).

In fact, my data is independent but not identically distributed as the variance depends on $n$ and converges to some limit $\sigma^2$. Only $|\hat \sigma_n^2 - \sigma^2| \rightarrow 0$ in probability can be established for the variance estimator at hand. So you say your proof would not work in this situation?

The crucial point seems to be where you choose $N_2$ such that the deterministic sequence $|\hat \sigma_n^2 - \sigma^2| < \epsilon /2$. If the sequence becomes deterministic by conditioning anyway, then this should still work, right?

Can you assume $\sup_k\sigma_k^2 < C$ for some $C>0$? Here $V[X_k] = \sigma_k^2$.

@Quertiopler maybe. Do you suggest that the strong law of large numbers could still be applicable? Then we'd need $\sup_k Var(\hat \sigma_k^2) < C$ I guess?

@Quertiopler any chance we could directly work with $|\hat \sigma_n^2 - \sigma^2| \overset{P}{\longrightarrow} 0$ instead?

It seems like @qwertiopler had the same error in line of thought as I did in my answer. You are right it should be $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}Var(\hat\sigma_n^2) < \infty$. I edited my answer accordingly.

@Lime91 with convergergence in probability, you have $\lim_n P(\vert\hat\sigma_n^2 - \sigma^2\vert\leq\epsilon)=1$ for all $\epsilon>0$, and with almost sure convergence you (basically) have $P(\lim_n\vert\hat\sigma_n^2 - \sigma^2\vert\leq\epsilon) = 1$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Notice how the $\lim_n$ is inside $P()$. As soon as you condition, you are working inside $P()$ (see my initial comment! you need to specify for which $x$ the condition has to hold) and $\hat\sigma_n^2$ will become deterministic. Thus, you also need the limit inside $P()$, i.e., almost sure convergence.
